# Storing data in Swipeable UI. Get Context in Fragments

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-scrollable-tabs

I am using the Scrollable tabs + Swipe Navigation for my project. I used Shared Preferences to store data of a form.
My onClick function for the save button of the page.

```
public void onClick(View v) {           
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = settings3.edit();
    editor3.putString("address", personal_info_address.getText().toString());
    editor3.putString("age", personal_info_age.getText().toString());
    editor3.putString("name", personal_info_name.getText().toString());
    editor3.putString("diseases", personal_info_diseases.getText().toString());
    editor3.commit();
}
```

I am unable to restore data after I reopen the application.
I am able to save my form details in a normal app with the same code, do I need to do something else as I am using the Scrollable tabs + Swipe Navigation.

**EDIT:**

I implemented the clickListener in the Fragment Class, here is my code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static EditText txtMessage;
    public static EditText emergencyno;
    Button button;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        context = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.services, container, false);
        emergencyno = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.settings_number);
        txtMessage = (EditText) root.findViewById(R.id.settings_msg);
        button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.save);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                String no = emergencyno.getText().toString();
                Log.d("HELLO : ", "data1");
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = context
                    .getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Log.d("HELLO : ", "data2" + context);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("message", msg);
                editor.putString("number", no);
                editor.commit();
                Log.d("HELLO : ", "data3" + msg + no);
                String message = sharedpreferences.getString("message",
                    "defValue");
                String phone_no = sharedpreferences.getString("number",
                    "defValue");
                txtMessage.setText(message);
                emergencyno.setText(phone_no);
                Log.d("HELLO : ", "data4" + message + phone_no);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

The log gives the correct values which I require. But on restarting the app the data isnt stored. I need to know how to get the Context.

Comment: Can you show your code from the activity? Pastebin might?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ikkXdPie

Comment: I think there might be some problem with buttons as i have also tried picking contacts from phonebook which wont work for the Scrollable tabs + Swipe navigation but it would work for the normal app.

Comment: I tried to debug the code and there is no entry for the button click in the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. The getActivity() in this fragment returned the Main Page of my app where I created the fragments so I defined my sharedpreferences function in the Main Page of the app(i.e. in the activity of this Fragment) as follows:

```
public static void putPref(String key, String value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    }


public static void putPref(String key, Boolean value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
    }

public static String getPref(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}

public static boolean getPrefBool(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, true);
}
```

And used the putPref function on clicking the button and getPref function on activity created.